# Procedure For Cloning Commerce Collection Taxonomy View Page?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, commerce

We are creating a store with Commerce Kickstart2. We need to duplicate the functionality of the Collection taxonomy. Essentially, we need -exactly- what the collection field does, but we need another one to organise products in a different way.

I've created a new Taxonomy term called 'Specialty'. I've successfully added that field to the Products. They can be searched and displayed and if I type in

/specialty/whatever-term

...I get a basic taxonomy term page of the correct products.

What I want to do is clone the View called 'collection-products' to a new view 'specialty-products' which does -exactly- the same thing, but for the new vocabulary 'Specialty'. I took a wild stab at it:

1. I copied/renamed the PHP file for the view into my theme folder

views-view--specialty-products--page.tpl.php

1. Edited that php replacing 'specialty' for all the vars 'collection'.
2. I cloned the collection-products view and replaced the 'collection' field with 'specialty' where necessary.

So (naturally) this does nothing.

Can someone provide guideance on where I went wrong or how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a view based on your products filtered to your taxonomy term. You should be able to do this with the views UI more easily than the way you're attempting to programatically.

I think you're misunderstand the theme folder altogether and how drupal presents the page that is rendered in the browser. The theme folder has mark up, images, and CSS that defines how your whole site is displayed, the views are generated, not stored as discrete files in your theme folder.

If you're on the kickstart demo store. Go to Product Categories, delete the defaults, add your own 'categories', and that should change the demo store to reflect your own set up. You should play with a default drupal set up to get familiar